# hebrew characters from txt file does not display on word after compile to JAR file using spire.doc.jar

Tags: java, ms-word, ascii, hebrew, spire.doc

I write in java code with spire.doc.jar that use BufferedReader to take some words from txt file and display it on word document at the end,
this is how it read the txt file:

```
BufferedReader abc = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("carNumbers.txt"));
```

everything works well but when I export my all code into jar file and run it in CMD
the word document come out with wired characters, instead of hebrew:

1. הריני לאשר בזאת

i get:

�׳™׳×׳•׳¨ ׳•׳©׳�׳™׳˜

hebrew words that gets added to the word file with finalText.appendText like that:

```
finalText.appendText(",בכבוד רב" );
```

gets added to the word doc just fine

what i need to do to fix that please?

Answer (score 1):

I fix that by changing this:

```
BufferedReader abc = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("carNumbers.txt"));
```

to this

```
BufferedReader abc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
    (new FileInputStream("carNumbers.txt"),"UTF-8"));
```